# How can I put this "\/\/cdn.apixu.com\/weather\/64x64\/day\/116.png" inside of a String, I have a problem with the "\/\/"

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to put `"-\/\/- Some URL for image"`
inside of a string but I have a problem with the `"-\/\/-"`, somebody can help me with that?

Comment: Taking your question verbating, the answer would be `let x = "-\\/\\/- Some URL for image"`. Given the tags you've assigned, I'm guessing there is more going on than this. Are you talking about reading or writing JSON? Transferring the string as an URL parameter? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: I need to puts inside uiimage this URL: \/\/cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png but i get this from the weather json, but I can't take the image from the url

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you're getting an image URL in a JSON response, which contains a property similar to this:

```
{ 
    "imageUrl": "\/\/cdn.apixu.com\/weather\/64x64\/day\/116.png"
}
```

Don't worry about the backslash-escaped `/` characters, that's just an artifact of the JSON encoding, and any JSON parser you use on iOS will remove those, yielding a String value of

```
//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png
```

Now, a URL starting with just `//` is called a protocol-relative URL, so you'll have to prepend whatever protocol you used to get the initial JSON response, most likely `https:`. This gives you

```
https://cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png
```

which indeed is a 64x64 pixel image that you can download and display in your app:

[image: 116.png]